# No route found for "GET /login/" in symfony

Tags: symfony, routes

Im use symfony 3.2., installed the package **fos_user**, configure it and all was well. But then I changed the controller added to it another way. Then, trying to go to the address /login I received an error: **No route found for "GET /login/"** And something redirect me to /login/

I tried to return the Aktion in the state in which it was before, cleaning the cache, the cache directory is completely removed, but nothing helped, the error still remains the same: No route found for "GET /login/"

my Controller:

```
# src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController
# Its work.

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @Route("/{category}/", name="category")
    */
    public function categoryAction($category)
    {
        return new Response('ok');
    }
}
```

My routing:

```
#app/config/routing.yml

app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation

admin:
    resource:
'@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
prefix: /profile
```

My security:

```
#app/config/security.yml

security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
            - { path: ^/login$,     role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/register,   role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/resetting,  role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/admin/,     role: ROLE_ADMIN }
            - { path: ^/,           role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I'm so angry, mud.

Comment: You don't have to add all the type of routing for `fos_user` when you have added `all.xml`. Remove others, and take `all.xml` to top of the page. It should work.